# Discrepancy in Email Sending Methods: Direct SendGrid API Integration vs. Laravel's Mail::to() Method

Tags: laravel

"When implementing email functionality in Laravel, I have observed that when using the direct SendGrid API integration in my code, emails are successfully sent without any issues. However, when utilizing Laravel's built-in Mail::to() method, I encountered an error message stating 'Expected response code "250/251/252" but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied".'

In my environment configuration file (env), I have only added the SendGrid API key:

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY='******************************'
```

I would appreciate assistance in resolving this discrepancy and ensuring consistent email delivery functionality across both implementations."

I attempted to send emails using Laravel's built-in Mail facade but encountered a 'Relaying denied' error. I expected successful email delivery. To address this, I utilized the SendGrid library directly and ensured the SENDGRID_API_KEY environment variable was correctly configured for authentication